# Making Require.JS work well with Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, amd

I am working in an environment which is AMD and using Require.js for that. It also uses KnockOut as the framework. The problem here is that I just downloaded a plug-in for knockout which highly depends on knockOut.

Now because of some problem that AMD nature of my application which are not exactly known to me, my plug-in does not work properly and throws error that Ko is not defined while loading my plug-in.

Any suggestion from those who has ever faces similar problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the plug-in you reference is the Mapping plugin you will need to do one of the following

1. Name your knockout script file "knockout.js"
2. Manually change define method in the mapping script so that it matches your name i.e. define(["**knockout-2.1.0**", "exports"], factory); That is from line 12 in the debug mapping script.

If it is a different plug-in please state which so that I can be of more help.

Comment: Hi Reid, I am using Ko-Grid plugin. Now, I am using Ko-grid.js as it is. do I need to add some define on top of it as I do with other files? You can find the file here:https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid/blob/master/KoGrid-1.2.0.debug.js

Comment: following code is there on ko-mapping:`(function (factory) {
 // Module systems magic dance.

 if (typeof require === "function" && typeof exports === "object" && typeof module === "object") {
  // CommonJS or Node: hard-coded dependency on "knockout"
  factory(require("knockout"), exports);
 } else if (typeof define === "function" && define["amd"]) {
  // AMD anonymous module with hard-coded dependency on "knockout"
  define(["knockout", "exports"], factory);
 } else {
  // <script> tag: use the global `ko` object, attaching a `mapping` property
  factory(ko, ko.mapping = {});
 }
}`

Comment: I got it to work by wrapping the entirety of Ko-grid.js in a require(['knockout-2.1.0', 'jquery'], function(ko, $) {  //code here });

Comment: here's the example file [https://gist.github.com/3758480](https://gist.github.com/3758480)

Comment: hi Reid, I wrapped the code in Require and I confirm that it is working. That was great help :). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Awesome Reid, I was lost at this for like 3 hours last night, so here's the deal:
What happen is that the mapping plugin (e.g.) define a hard-coded dependency to knockout, for node, commonjs or amd, for requirejs you need to specify your knockout plugin "route" or "path", e.g. my knockout file is renamed to ko.js and mapping to ko.mapping.js and their are in the folder plugins that I rename in the path config as "lib"

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js/",
    paths: {
        "lib" : "plugins"
    }
});
```

In that case the line that has to be renamed in the mapping plugin is the same but not with the version number, you just need to put the location of your ko file.

```
if (typeof require === "function" && typeof exports === "object" && typeof module === "object") {
    // CommonJS or Node: hard-coded dependency on "knockout"
    factory(require("knockout"), exports);
} else if (typeof define === "function" && define["amd"]) {
    // AMD anonymous module with hard-coded dependency on "knockout"
    define(["lib/ko", "exports"], factory);
} else {
    // <script> tag: use the global `ko` object, attaching a `mapping` property
    factory(ko, ko.mapping = {});
}
```

In my experience I have my ko file under lib and renamed to ko, so if your file is under "js/knockout/" folder and is renamed to knockout-debbug-last-2.2.0.js you need to change the same line to

```
define( [ 'js/knockout/knockout-debbug-last-2.2.0' ] , factory );
```

That hard-coded line is what make the plugin load fail.

note: I wrote this as an answer instead of a comment because code in comments looks really bad.